# Is it possible to deactivate IPN for specific payments on paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Our shop can handle IPNs (Instant Payment Notification) for regular payments.

We offer donations over paypal too, but can't handle this IPNs, because we don't keep track of the donations on the shop side. And don't want to atm.

Is it possible to deactive IPN for e.g. donations or do we need to create a seperate paypal account for this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Apart from my answer, one more suggestion: Why you just don't ignore the IPNs coming from donations ?

Comment: I want to, but the same interface is used for both types of IPNs by default. So to specify a custom `notify_url` in the donation form leading to a url which just returns a HTTP 200 works great for me! thx  @robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a notify_url for your donation  going to a different location than your regular IPN script.
As long as that location answers it with a HTTP 200 OK, it's fine for PayPal.

So essentially you'd have:
- Your store setting a proper notify_url for each transaction
OR
- An IPN URL set up on your PayPal Profile
AND
- A specific custom notify_url for donations. This can be a plain .html or .txt file.*

This would work because notify_url overrides whatever is set up on your PayPal Profile.

Comment: i specified a custom `notify_url` for donations. works for me, thank you very much robert!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't desable paypal IPN for the specific payment 
but, you can separate donation and other payment using different `invoice-id` 
if if payment made by donation you can prefix any keyword on `Invoide-id` like `donation-001`

it is a simple and best method you can try..